# Muliple Related FK in EF Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have `segmentation` class which have some price range, related `office` and `route`. I want routeCountyMap table with route and county related but I can only assign county once per segmentation.
E.g. for *200-400 segmentation* has *A* and *B* office and *A* office has *E,F,G* routes; if there is *X* county with *F* route, there won't be able fore 2*00-400 segmentation*. My codes are below, how can arrange it?

```
public class segment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid segmentId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Guid organisationId { get; set; }
}

public class office
{
    [Key]
    public Guid officeId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Guid segmentId { get; set; }
    public segment segment { get; set; }
}

public class route
{
    [Key]
    public Guid routeId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Guid officeId { get; set; }
    public office office { get; set; }
}

public class county
{
    [Key]
    public Guid countyId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Guid cityId { get; set; }
}

public class routeCountyMap
{
    public Guid routeCountyMapId { get; set; }
    public Guid routeId { get; set; }
    public Guid countyId { get; set; }
    public route route { get; set; }
    public county county { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    [Key]
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class routeUserMap
{
    [Key]
    public Guid routeUserMapId { get; set; }
    public Guid routeId { get; set; }
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
    public route route { get; set; }
    public user user { get; set; }
}
```

[DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1x7u.png)